# Create static inner function object using new window[]

Tags: javascript

I have a static inner function:

```
function A() {

}

A.B = function() {

}
```

I am not able to create function object of inner static function using:

```
new window['A.B'](); //Does not work
```

where as

```
new window['A'](); //Works
```

&

```
new A.B(); //Also works if I create inner static function object directly.
```

Does anyone know how to create static inner function object using window?

Answer (score 3):

`A.B` is not the property of `window`. `A` is the property of `window` and `B` is the property of `A`. So if you really want to do this with brackets for some strange reason, it's `new window['A']['B']()`.

If you want to access any property of an object while descending based on dots, that's not built-in.

```
function descend(obj, path) {
    var parts = path.split('.');

    for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        obj = obj[parts[i]];
    }

    return obj;
}

// var B = descend(window, 'A.B');
// new B()
```